# format specifier for apr apr_time_h

Tags: c, apr

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
    Apache protable runtime 1.4
    c89 and compiling in -m32 mode
```

Code:

```
apr_time_t time_msecs = 0;
time_msecs = apr_time_as_msec(apr_time_now());
printf("Time in msecs [ %lu ]\n", time_msecs);
```

I get the following warning:

```
format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘apr_time_t’ [-Wformat]
```

Apart from casting. What is the correct format specifier for this type (apr_time_t)?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

APR contains a macro called `APR_TIME_T_FMT` which might do what you want.

When building your format string, you use it like that (assuming it works like the stdint macros): `printf("time: %" APR_TIME_T_FMT, value);`
You could also simply cast the value to the appropriate type.

Comment: I did cast it at first. But I was wondering if there was a format specifier I could use instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
printf("The current time: %" APR_TIME_T_FMT "[us]\n", apr_time_now());
```

[Tutorial](http://dev.ariel-networks.com/apr/apr-tutorial/html/apr-tutorial-9.html).